# Why list indexing [-4:0] not working while [0:4] works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If negative list indexing is starting from the end the list and let's say we have:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and `l[0:3]` and `l[:3]` returns same values while `l[-3:0]` returns *an empty list* and `l[-3:]` returns `[3,4,5]`

What is the logic behind not allowing `list[-x:0]` to return the list?

Comment: Index `0` is the beginning of the sequnce. As the `end` it will always return an empty sequence.

Comment: I do understand that. But why it is not changing in the negative indexing? Then that means indexes are assigned when a list is created and never change after that? Logically 0 is right after -1 and it should have returned the hole list

Comment: “[1,2,3,4,5][-3:] returns [2,3,4,5]” — Does it? Try again.

Comment: Why did you role back a correction in your punctuation?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor should be that that the output is `[3,4,5]` right? :-)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor because there was nothing changed

Comment: Only the punctuation was corrected (But I forgot to add the word “of”, at present it says something about a “list and let's” what ever that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l[-3:0]` tries to slice from 3 from behind towards 0 - that is the same as `l[2:0]` .. that slices nothing because the first value > second value.

`l[-3:]` can be read as `l[-3:len(l)]` - so `l[2:5]` which returns the slice.

You would need `l[-3:0:-1]` for that to work - but thats mind boggling slicing which I try to avoid. ( `print( [1,2,3,4,5][-3:0:-1]` --> `[3, 2]` ) because it also reverses the slice "orientation" to backwards instead of forwards

`l[-3:]` slices from 3 from behind till the end.

Comment: @I'd mention also `l[-3::-1]` that _possibly_ is what the OP was really asking for...

Answer (score 1):

The full notation of slice in Python is the following:

```
s[start:end:step]
```

That being said it provides *useful defaults* for the values, as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to
>   zero, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being
>   sliced.

So when you do something like:

```
s[1:]
```

under the hood this is done:

```
s[1:len(s)]
```

Note that in both cases *step* defaults to `1`. In most languages when you want to access the last element of a list for example you do something like:

```
s[len(s) - 1]
```

Python negative indexing is a sort of *syntactic sugar* on that notation so :

```
l[-1] = l[len(l) - 1]
l[-2] = l[len(l) - 2]
...
```

Then when you do:

```
l[-3:]
```

this is done:

```
l[len(l)-3:len(l)]
```

So, instead of `0` you should use `len(l)` as the last index:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l[-3:len(l)])
```

**Output**

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Note that `l[-3:0]` returns the empty list because `len(l) - 3 > 0`, i.e. the first index is greater than the second and *step* is `1`.

**Further**

1. [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Well `0` in front works, but at last... won't work, same with this:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l[2:0]
[]
>>>
```

because python is thinking zero at the end...

So that's virtually equivalent to:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l[:0]
[]
>>>
```

since of course there is nothing before first element, if there was, that thing wouldn't be first element, it would be second.

Comment: but >>> l[-3:-1] does work and return [3, 4] and what you are writing is totally different thing

Comment: @Rarblack But wait... `l[-1]` is `5`, and please don't down-vote answers you get without knowing the full thing!

Answer (score 0):

Negative indexes operate from the end of the list.
Say if you want to get the last 3 items, you could do:

```
# Reversing and restoring the order
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(reversed(reversed(my_list)[:3]))

# Subtracting from the size
size = len(my_list)
print(my_list[size-3:])
```

But instead you can type

```
my_list[-3:]
```

Which in words would state *get me the slice of the list starting from the third item at the end of the list*

So you have to be aware of what your asking for.

```
# Slice from the x'th element at the end till the end of the list
my_list[-x:]

# Slice from the x'th element at the end till the y'th element at the end of the list
my_list[-x:-y]

# Slice from the x'th element at the end till the y'th element from the start of the list. 
# Only valid if len(my_list) - y < x and y > 0
my_list[-x:y]
```